# Is the existence of undecidable propositions decidable?

Tags: lo.logic

In proving his [first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem) Godel constructed a proposition that is undecidable, i.e. neither provable nor disprovable within a consistent formal system $F$ that contains elementary arithmetic.

My question is:

> Can the (true) statement **$D$="There exist propositions in $F$ that are undecidable"** be proved within some formal system $F$ to which the first incompleteness theorem applies?

Note that $D$ is expressible as $$\neg (\forall _n \exists_m [(\Pi_m \text{ proves } P_n) \lor (\Pi_m \text{ proves }\neg P_n)])$$

where $P_n$ is the $n$-th proposition and $\Pi_m$ is the $m$-th proof. Hence this should be a valid arithmetical proposition in the Godel encoding.

Comment: No. If $F$ proves that some statements are undecidable in $F$, then $F$ would prove $F$ is consistent (as otherwise it proves everything), which is impossible by Godel's second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: To build off of Wojowu's statement, it is possible for a system F to prove "If F is consistent, then there are undecidable statements in F." But what this really is in some sense a theorem of F + Con F being imported into F.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you for your answer, much appreciated.

Comment: @IvanMeir In principle there are very weak theories that violate second incompleteness theorem (although, in comparision to say $\mathsf{PA}$, for this theories it is far less clear what should count as "natural" formalization of provability). The most well-known examples of theories violating G2 are due to D. Willard, see for example his paper "Self-verifying axiom systems, the incompleteness theorem and related reflection principles". There is also my recent example https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00877 . By slight modifications of those examples it is easy to get provably undecidable sentences.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov Thank you for your response which is very interesting. So if I understand correctly, there exist theories that the first incompleteness theory applies to but not the second in which case we should be able to prove undecidability for certain sentences? I was wondering how much of standard arithmetic do such theories contain?

Comment: @IvanMeir The key limitation of this kind of theories is that they couldn't prove totality of the successor function. It isn't immediately clear that those theories directly provide examples of provably undecidable sentences. However, it is easy to modify those theories so that this examples will be present. If you add an additional unary predicate $P(x)$ to the theory $H_{<\omega}$ from my paper, then the same argument used to show that $H_{<\omega}\vdash \mathsf{Con}(H_{<\omega})$ will show that $\exists x\;P(x)$ is provably undecidable for $H_{<\omega}$.